# Styled radio buttons (jquery?)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, radio-button

I need the functionality of a radio selection, without the style.

How can I style something (anything) to work like a radio button, and capture the input in a form?

Comment: @Kevin can you elaborate on the functionality you're talking about? You want radio button functionality without it looking like a radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this](http://www.weblee.co.uk/2009/05/30/radio-button-replacement-with-style/)?

I think what they've done is just hidden the actual radio buttons on the page, replacing them with fancy looking icons, images and text.  Clicking these elements forces the radio buttons to change behind the scenes.

There's all kinds of them:

http://www.chriserwin.com/scripts/crir/index.php

http://lipidity.com/fancy-form/

http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

I [wrote a tutorial](http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/custom-inputs) about how to create customized radio buttons with CSS only. Basically you hide the radio button itself and style its label how you want, it is pretty easy. Maybe this helps :)

Comment: can you help me with this, basically I am trying to archive this: only allow 1 radio box to be checked, meaning that when you check a radio box, the rest should be unchecked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616129

Comment: add same `name` attribute to each of the radio buttons